# Is there a way to define and iterate over an array in ember handlebars templates?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on a styleguide and need to iterate over an array in a handlebars template.

I know that you can iterate over objects or other variables when passed into a template, but is there a way to iterate over a collection defined in the template? I think this breaks the "no-logic in views" concept that handlebars pushes, but I imagine this is a common use case.

```js
{{#each ['success', 'warning', 'error', 'info'] key="@index" as |type|}}
  <div class='banners-container'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='banner banner-{{type}} has-icon has-dismiss'>
        <p>Banner {{type}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I would expect this to output 4 collections of the `banners-container` elements, but it's not outputting anything.

What's the best way to handle this use case?

Comment: `collection defined in the template` ? I don't get it. You do you want to define a collection in template ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [array](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#array) helper from [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) to compose arrays directly in the template:

```
{{#each (array 1 2 3) as |numbers|}}
  {{numbers}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define your array in your `controller/component` files and use that `property` in `hbs`. say

`app/controllers/application.js`

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Controller.extend({
  status: A(['success', 'warning', 'error', 'info']),
})
```

in your app/templates/application.hbs

```
{{#each status as |type|}}
  {{type}}
{{/each}}
```

You can have a look at [ember native array function](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Farray/A)